# how do I get hbase rowkey in pig

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I'm new to Hbase and pig.
I have a hbase table and I want to get max rowkey from my pig script.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to interogate the [Meta](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.catalog) server to get the end row key of the last region in the table. All values are sorted so it shouldn't be hard to get the last region.

The info:regioninfo (serialized [HRegionInfo](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HRegionInfo.html) instance for this region) contains the information you are looking for.

If pig doesn't support this directly, you can write a [User defined function](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/udf.html), put it in the classpath and call it from your script.

I don't know a better way.